# Accessing and adding values inside nested array

Tags: laravel

I have different 'spots' inside multiple arrays against each city name. Like Houston has two arrays each with a different 'spots' value.
What I want to do is add those two 'spots' values against Houston or any cities name, inside maybe a new array. So that when I want to access 'spots' I get the total of 'spots' of a single city.

This is the code inside the controller:

```
foreach ($request->city as $city) {
                $citySpots[$city] = Controller::select('spots')
                                    ->where('city', $city)
                                    ->get()
                                    ->toArray();
            }

dd($citySpots);
```

dd value:

```
array:2 [▼
  "Houston" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:1 [▼
      "spots" => "20"
    ]
    1 => array:1 [▼
      "spots" => "10"
    ]
  ]
  "New York" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:1 [▼
      "spots" => "500"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each city has visited spots , i am suggesting you count the spots and then groupby the name of the city :

**it goes somthing like this**

```
foreach ($request->city as $city) {
                $citySpots[$city] = DB::table('table_name') 
                                    ->select(DB::raw('sum(spots) as spots'))
                                    ->where('city', $city)
                                    ->groupBy('city')
                                    ->get()
                                    ->toArray();
            }

dd($citySpots);
```

**dd should be**

```
array:2 [▼
  "Houston" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:1 [▼
      "spots" => "30"
    ]
  ]
  "New York" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:1 [▼
      "spots" => "500"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: Thank you sir you are a savior. the only thing is that spot is object now ``` "Houston" => array:1 [▼ 0 => {#1282 ▼ +"spot": 30.0 } ] ``` Is it possible to convert it to array?

Comment: and Is it possible to achieve all this with Eloquent?

Comment: ig not with eloquent directly , try this instead of toArray() : 
```->map(function ($item) {return array_merge(...$item->toArray());```

Comment: Thank you. much appreciated  